# How to download file from bamboo in zip format using rest api?

Tags: bamboo

I have a need in my project where i would get the uri of the folder and using it i have to download the files in the uri (in zipped format) as the normal format is leading to the default html file.Please let me know how i can do that with bamboo rest api